# Why my ASP.NET project doesn't do anything?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to write a project to show some data from 2 tables in `MMABooks` database. These codes work in C# but they don't work in ASP.Net. Actually, it does nothing and I don't get any errors! Why? What is the problem?

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SqlExpress;" +
                "Initial Catalog=MMABooks;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
string selectStatement = "SELECT Customers.Name, Customers.City, States.StateName " +
                "FROM Customers " +
                "INNER JOIN States " +
                "ON Customers.State = States.StateCode " +
                "WHERE Name LIKE @Name";

 SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
 SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "%");

 connection.Open();
  var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
  GridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [`GridView1.DataBind()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx) in the ASP.NET which *Binds the data source to the `GridView`* after the last line.

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `GridView1.DataSource = dt;` After `GridView1.DataSource = dt;`

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SqlExpress;" +
                "Initial Catalog=MMABooks;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
string selectStatement = "SELECT Customers.Name, Customers.City, States.StateName " +
                "FROM Customers " +
                "INNER JOIN States " +
                "ON Customers.State = States.StateCode " +
                "WHERE Name LIKE @Name";

 SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
 SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "%");

 connection.Open();
  var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
  GridView1.DataSource = dt;
  GridView1.DataBind();//you are missing this
```